# i am having issues running ansible-playbook (syntax error)

Tags: ansible

I followed multiple tutorials but I am still always getting the same error.

first.yaml

```
---

- hosts: all
 task

 - name: download httpd
 yum:
 - name: httpd
   state: latest
```

when i run > ansible-playbook first.yaml 
I get this:

```
ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
 mapping values are not allowed in this context

The error appears to be in '/home/ansible/Document/first.yaml': line 5, column 8, but may be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

- hosts: all
       ^ here
```

Thanks

Comment: [Learn yaml in y minutes](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/). Indentation is syntactically significant. Your above file is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Hi try this one (from [docs.ansible.com](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/yum_module.html)),

```
- name: install the latest version of Apache
  yum:
    name: httpd
    state: latest
```

Before `name: httpd` there is no `-` character in the provided example.

Comment: pls look at @smily answer, there is a copy/paste example of the playbook

Answer (score 0):

First problem is Indentation. Please see below.
Secondly the keyword is **tasks** not **task** and you need a colon(:) after tasks.

```
---

- hosts: all
  tasks:
  - name: download httpd
    yum:
     name: httpd
     state: latest
```

Comment: Please mark as solution and upvote if it helped you.